# Ruby on Rails undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue while deleting user posts:

> undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/new'
  get 'user/new'
  root to:'pages#home'
  get '/home', to:'pages#home'
  get '/help', to:'pages#help'
  get '/about', to:'pages#about'
  get '/contact',  to:'pages#contact'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  post '/micro_posts', to: 'microposts#create'
  delete '/micro_posts', to: 'microposts#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
end


# microposts_controller.rb 

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.micro_posts.build(req_params)

    if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Post created"
        redirect_to root_url    
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'pages/home'

    end     
  end

  def destroy   
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Post deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end    

  private

  def req_params
    params.require(:micro_post).permit(:content)
  end

  def correct_user
    @micropost = current_user.micro_posts.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end    
end

# _micro_post.html.erb file

<li id="micropost" ><%= micro_post.id %>
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micro_post.user, size: 50), micro_post.user %>
  <span class="user" ><%= link_to micro_post.user.name, micro_post.user %></span><br/>
  <span class="content" ><%= micro_post.content %></span>
  <br/> 
  <span  class="timestamp">
  posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micro_post.created_at) %> ago    

  <% if current_user?(micro_post.user) %>
    <%= link_to '  | Delete', micro_posts_path, method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>
  <% end %>    
  </span>
  <br/>    
</li>
```

Now what I figured out is that my error is in microposts_controller.rb
file in the reference method "correct_user", because it could not find
the id of the micropost and returning nil. And so we can't call the
destroy method on nil object. Can you please tell me why it is not
finding the micropost id?

```
Started DELETE "/micro_posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-21 21:43:17 +0500
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by MicropostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"aNeBnIy/JOrWz+sQdzU2w06faILW2dM+f8SPwmXVmJs1XfJ8OqbkgPVwkpoY/HBjh8YJhVPWZ4BC1Onxg0AtWw=="}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:16
  MicroPost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "micro_posts".* FROM "micro_posts" WHERE "micro_posts"."id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:36
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 56ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:22:in `destroy
```

Comment: The error should be telling you exactly what line in what file. You are calling `destroy` on an object that is `nil`. In this case, `@micropost` is probably a `nil` value when you call `@micropost.destroy`. So the value of `@micropost` has not been set.

Comment: lurker in correct_user method in microposts_controller.rb file the @micropost  instance variable is returned as nil.where as i following along a tutorial where instructor used the same way

Comment: it will be helpful if you provide params here when deleting

Comment: {"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"r86/8odRAkJYffFDVfiJW7zPQ1JP/wQczaVQXxE8XPhBk/5P6hUo02PfjfJgFnXs+T0ljuOonYx8hpF7F4gC+A=="}

Comment: nitanshuverma                                                                                         
     <%= link_to '  | Delete', micro_posts_path, method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>  is the path i specified is right..i double checked it  using debugger but at byebug it still showing @micropost is nil

Comment: Do you have a micro_post in the db to destroy?

Comment: I did not get you what are you saying? but i have microposts in the db.At console i can count those micro posts for a particular user but here in controller its not working...where as if a specify a particular id then that micro post gets destroyed but not picking up the micropost's id through params in correct_user

Comment: In your delete link change `micro_posts_path` to `micro_post_path(micro_post)`

Comment: @Vasilisa undefined method destroy for nil class

Comment: @TheDigitalAcademy could you please post the full server log for this action?

Comment: @Vasilisa please check i added the server log

Comment: @TheDigitalAcademy what if `micro_post_path(micro_post.id)`?

Comment: @Vasilisa i tried it before but it also not working

Comment: Wow, what I found! Why do you need `delete '/micro_posts'` in routes when you have `resources :microposts`? Change it to ``delete '/micro_posts/:id'` if you really need it

Comment: @Vasilisa you are right.but when when i delete that specified path then i got an error stating that "no route matches[DELETE] /micro_posts"..and if i delete the route for create action it agains prompts similar error

Comment: If you delete it you need to use default `micropost_path(micro_post.id)`. Note, there is no underscore. You have some problems with underscores, I think. Is your model called Micropost or MicroPost? If second, you need to define `resources :micro_posts` and change controller name to MicroPosts (and the file name too). Just be consistent in naming

Comment: @Vasilisa yes model name is "MicroPost" and  controller name is "MicropostController".. is something wrong with controllers name?

Comment: @TheDigitalAcademy, it is better to use the same names for models, controllers and views - in this case rails magic will work for you.

Comment: @Vasilisa thank you so much dear for helping out me ..really thankful to  you..God bless you

Comment: its working now..the problem was controller and model names were different

Comment: @TheDigitalAcademy happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks the problem in your `correct_user` method. Try to remove it and use this way:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :set_micropost, only: :destroy

  ...

  def set_micropost
    @micropost ||= Micropost.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= link_to '  | Delete', @micropost, method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>
```

Comment: Try to replace in my variant `@micropost` to `micropost_path(@micropost)` in erb

Comment: hi mate still showing the nil class error..tried every thing told until @mechnicov

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, I'll convert my comments to the answer, to not leave the question unanswered.

You have a naming issue. The model is `MicroPost`, but the controller is `MicropostsController`. That's why you're trying to create custom routes.

You need to rename controller to `MicroPostsController` and it's file to `micro_posts_controller.rb`. Remove from routes.rb these 2 lines:

```
post '/micro_posts', to: 'microposts#create'
delete '/micro_posts', to: 'microposts#destroy'
```

And change `microposts` to `micro_posts` (note the underscore) here:

```
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Use `micro_post_path(micro_post)` for delete link in the view

Answer (score 0):

Yep you have to set the value of @micropost beofre trying to destroy it.
Usually this is something you want to do with the params hash so you could have sth like `@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])` at the beginning of your `destroy` method. This is a line you might want to use in other methods in you controller so you can refactor it as follow

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_micropost, only: [:destroy]

 ...

  private

  def set_micropost
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Couldn't find MicroPost without an ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be passing the id param to your delete route in your view.

Instead of this:

`<%= link_to '  | Delete', micro_posts_path, method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>`

Try this:
`<%= link_to '  | Delete', micro_posts_path(micro_post.id), method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>`

Comment: did not work brother..can  you please tell why it could be returning nil?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```rb
<%= link_to '  | Delete', micro_post_path(micro_post), method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>
```

The issue is that you are using a collection route. `micro_posts_path` is a collection route and you need to use a member route which takes resource id. So in this scenario we remove `s` from the route and it becomes `micro_post_path` that is a member route.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't noticed that @zeitnot had answered before me with the same recommendation.

---

I think your issue is your delete link not referencing the actual object. You're not passing the object id, so `params[:id]` is always going to be nil.

Try this to see if it works:

```
<% if current_user?(micro_post.user) %>
  <%= link_to '  | Delete', micro_post_path(micro_post), method: :delete , data: { confirm: "Are you sure" } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the problem was my model and controller  names were not matching that's why id was returned as nil object